# MVC Deserializes null into "null" (string)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm passing an object from jQuery to a MVC3 Controller via a $.ajax POST.  While debugging using Developer Tools, I can see the object I'm assigning to the ajax data property.  The object contains properties whose value is null.  When I debug the Controller, the properties which were null in the JS Debugger are now "null" (strings).

Why is this?  What can I do to prevent this from happening?

C# Object

```
public class User
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript Object

```
var user = {
Name: null
}
```

Controller Method

```
public JsonResult HelloWorld(User user) { .. some logic .. }
```

ajax Call

```
var data = user;
$.ajax({
url: '/Controller/HelloWorld/',
data: data,
type: 'post',
success: ...
error: ...
})
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code (both js and cs)?

Comment: We aren't doing anything special.  Create a c# object, create a javascript object which matches (leaving some properties as null), then use jQuery ajax to POST that object to a Controller method.  The object is coming over with the properties as "null" so the logic within the Controller method doesn't matter.

Comment: cool, can you show *how* you're doing that `POST` in JavaScript then?

Comment: I've updated the question for you.

Comment: honest question. Have you tried specifying `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`? (not 100% sure if it helps in this case tho)

Comment: @LeeGunn you *are* missing something. It's `null` in js, but it's `string` in cs (with the value of null)

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448150/asp-net-mvc-receives-null-as-a-string-instead-of-null) link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap, that's an unfortunate side effect with the default model binder. You could avoid it by either not including null properties in the request at all or by using a JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("HelloWorld", "Controller")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Name: null }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

- `contentType: 'application/json'`.
- `JSON.stringify` around the data parameter in order to convert to a JSON string the request.

Comment: so it turns out `contentType` helps a little in this case after all

Comment: Yes it helps because it is now the JSON value provider factory using the JavaScriptDeserializer class which handles the parsing instead of the default model binder.

Comment: yeah, I suggested that but the OP never replied. As for the `null`-"null" issue, I recommended the approach in a different question but `JSON.stringify` is definitely the way to go, so you don't have to check each individual property... +1